# Can I run an Azure storage queue processor in a webAPI project?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage-queues

Within Azure Functions and WebApps it is possible to automate execution of Storage queues by setting up a method linked to that queue by a QueueTrigger.  I would like to accomplish the same thing, but I want it all compiled as part of my Web API so it is all in one project/compile/upload.

I have played around and I can setup the functions within my webapi project and compile them.  I have added all the necessary packages and configuration, but the queue does not fire and no errors occur.

Comment: Not totally sure what you're asking, as your question is fairly high-level: what do you mean by "queue processor?" And are you talking about Storage Queues? Service Bus Queues? If you're referring to the queue binding of Azure Functions, that's just one of many ways you could consume queue content (there are SDKs supporting direct access to queues). Please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: Added that it is a storage queue.  In a function or a webapp you can automate the execution of the queue messages, I want to do that outside of a function or webapp.

Comment: So your main objective is that you want all of these contained within a single project so that you can deploy it easily in one shot? If so, have you taken a look at CI/CD?

Comment: @ZiadAkiki I'm not sure how ci/cd would help?  We already use continuous deployment.

Comment: Use a normal web api project for your APIs and use an azure function to handle the queue. You will then use CI to automatically deploy to both the normal app service (I assume the web api is hosted in an app service) and the azure function to its respective app as well.

Comment: The question is how NOT to use functions.  I know how to use a function to accomplish this already.